# Intercepting all messages to an external process

Tags: visual-c++, message

Just for the sake of seeing if it is possible, I am trying to write an app that will intercept all mouse and keyboard messages sent to an external process. By going through a couple of tutorials I have managed to inject a dll into the external process, but I am struggling to work out how to intercept and prevent messages from getting to the external process now that it is injected.

I have tried using hooks, but I couldn't modify or prevent messages from reaching the external process; I could only look at what they were. That then lead me to subclassing windows, which seems to hold the most promise.

**My question is**: Is subclassing the right way to intercept and block messages from reaching the extrenal app; and if it is, does that mean that I need to subclass every window in the app in order to prevent the mouse and keyboard messages from reaching it?

Comment: Subclassing windows in a program that doesn't expect it violates your Hippocratic oath, it frequently ends up with a dead program.  Use SetWindowsHookEx(), it was made for this.

Comment: I have managed to set up hooks before, which hook should I use? WH_CALLWNDPROC looks perfect but how do I stop the message from being passed on?

Comment: WH_GETMESSAGE, it allows modifying the message and works for messages posted to the queue.  Like mouse and keyboard messages.

Comment: ah yes, of course, you are quite right. I didn't realise the LPARAM was a MSG. Thank you for your time.